# Does SQL Server creates Non clustered index on all columns of a table by default

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

Will sql server create any default non-clustered index? Should we really put all FK as non-clustered index? What is the trade-off here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, SQL Server does not automatically create non-clustered indexes.
A clustered index is created automatically based on the primary key, unless your `CREATE TABLE` statement says otherwise.

Yes, I would recommend indexing foreign key columns because these are the most likely to be JOIN'd/searched against using `IN`, `EXISTS`, etc. However, be aware that an index on a low cardinality set of values (gender for example) will be relatively useless because there's not enough difference in the values.

The trade-off with all indexes is that they can speed up data retrieval, but slow down data insertion/updating/deletion.  There's also maintenance that needs to be performed because they can get fragmented (like hard drives) but also might not get used over time.  Indexes also take up drive space.

Comment: thanks...What happens if there is non-clustered key and no non-clustered key on FK that i am using it to join with the child table. What scan does it use? Full, Index seek and Index scan?

Comment: Depends on the query, the index, the table statistics & the optimizer -- it means looking at the explain plan.