# Does SQL Server creates Non clustered index by default

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, clustered-index

Ya, it is **a duplicate** of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781088/does-sql-server-creates-non-clustered-index-on-all-columns-of-a-table-by-default). But I just needs a clarification on [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/02/10/sql-server-primary-key-and-nonclustered-index-in-simple-words/) by **Pinal Dave**, which says the following:

> Scenario 4: Primary Key defaults to Clustered Index with other index
>   defaults to Non-clustered index
>
> In this case we will create two indexes on the both the tables but we
>   will not specify the type of the index on the columns. When we check
>   the results we will notice that Primary Key is automatically defaulted
>   to Clustered Index and another column as a Non-clustered index.
>
> ```
> -- Case 4 Primary Key and Defaults
> USE TempDB
> GO
> -- Create table
> CREATE TABLE TestTable
> (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
> Col1 INT NOT NULL UNIQUE)
> GO
> -- Check Indexes
> SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) TableObject,
> [name] IndexName,
> [Type_Desc]
> FROM sys.indexes
> WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'TestTable'
> GO
> -- Clean up
> DROP TABLE TestTable
> GO
> ```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only indexes that get created automatically:

- the **clustered index** on your primary key (unless you specify otherwise - if you define your primary key to be nonclustered, then a **nonclustered** index will be created)
- a **unique nonclustered index** when you apply a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` to a column (or set of columns)

Answer (score 2):

Just to spell it out - the Result of Pinal Dave's example are indexes similar to the following:

```
TestTable   PK__TestTabl__3214EC2703317E3D  CLUSTERED
TestTable   UQ__TestTabl__A259EE55060DEAE8  NONCLUSTERED
```

Which can be explained as follows:

*PK Clustered*

If a table is created *with a primary key*, then it is a [Clustered Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189051(v=sql.105).aspx#sectionToggle2), and the Clustered Index is [defaulted to the Primary Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186342.aspx#Implementations) unless you specify otherwise. 
(Tables without a Clustered Index are [Heaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213609.aspx))

*UQ Nonclustered*

SQL does **not** usually create any non-clustered indexes on a table by default.

However, as Marc has pointed out, because the table has a column with a `UNIQUE` constraint, `(Col1 INT NOT NULL UNIQUE)`, MS SQL *implements* the constraint as a unique, non-clustered index on that column.

See also: [Is the Sql Server Unique Key also an Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366186/is-the-sql-server-unique-key-also-an-index)